# Transformers for time series - what is the role of the encoder?

Tags: time-series, transformer

I am trying to become more familiar with transformers by applying them to simple sequences like uni-variate time series. For now I am reading the papers.

One of the important parts of transformers seems to be that attention mechanism compares every point in the prior series to every other prior point. That makes sense. What makes less sense is why one needs a decoder, in general? For example, here is the architecture of the Informer model (https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.07436)

[image]

Is the encoder-decoder needed here because the model is trained to be general enough to work for many different time-series? Thus input into the encoder is needed to *bias* the model to work for a specific type of time series during the application?

What if I wanted to train a model of only one type of time series? Could I not remove the encoder part and aim to get all the knowledge of the time series to be implanted into the decoder weights via training?

Thanks

Comment: Mr. Cryo, do you have any academic article references where only the decoder of transformers was implemented for time series forecasting?

Comment: Not sure this is the right place to ask these questions. I don't think I have exactly what you want, but here are some papers I found useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.07015 https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.13408 https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.08424.pdf https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.07125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decoder is there because their goal is to predict the future points of the time series. (And one of the focuses of the Informer model is to do that for a run of points efficiently.)

If your purpose is something else, such as classification, you could use just the encoder part of the model, putting a classification head on top.

By the way, using encoder+decoder is not about making it making it more general-purpose. Using a variety of training data, and usually more layers and embedding dimension, are what would do that.

Comment: Thanks @Darren, but what about removing the encoder? Why is that needed? Won't decoder, with partially filled input, do just fine? If I train it with this setting, of course?

Comment: Looking at this [ETSformer: Exponential Smoothing Transformers for Time-series Forecasting](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.01381), for example, they only have one input for the encoder/decoder block, so not sure these should even be classified as separate.

Comment: Yes, you could also make a decoder only transformer model for time series prediction. In NLP models compare BERT, which is Encoder-only, GPT which is Decoder-only, and say T5 which is Encoder-Decoder. It is possible to make each of them do any of the tasks the others can do.

Comment: To add to that: the choice of which to do use would come down to which is most efficient way to do it.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for - thanks!